# How to revive my windows 10 after installing ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows-10

I have 3 hard disk drives, 500 G blue, 1Tgreen, 1T blue cavier!
I have installed a windows 7 on my 500Gig HDD. and recently (actually couple of months ago)
I installed windows 10 64bit on my newly purchased 1T blue cavier hdd.
again after sometime, I needed to install ubuntu. so I split my last partition from the 1T blue cavier hdd and installed the OS.
and my windows 10 boot is gone.
I tried to fix it, I got the windows 10 working and the linux boot was gone!
after sometime, I got the ubuntu and windows7 ok, and now the windows 10 is gone!.
What should I do now, I both need all of these Oses and I have no idea how to make this work.

### note

I used Ubuntu's `boot repair` and I think I messed up something there!

Comment: If you try to install the Linux bootloader can't you manually add the windows boot locations? Also, Windows 10 can use UEFI, maybe that's part of the problem?

Comment: well, I have no Idea, windows 10 is there, but not accessible(no boot and stuff), and I'm afraid to pop the win10 disk and repair the boot and my ubuntu os gets destroyed! I cant risk that.
I'm left with ubuntu and win7 for the past 3 months!

Comment: no thats not it. 
Actually I used boot repair. and that messed it up!

Answer (score 0):

If you do it correctly you shouldn't have any trouble running Windows and Linux on the same drive, different partition. It's not the best idea but it does work.

When installing, make sure you only format the partitions that are relevant to your OS.

For example, if you want Linux on partition x and Windows on partition y, when installing Linux only format partition x. Remember they, use different formats.

If your getting issues with Grub, just use your windows installation disc and repair the installation, it should work.

Another suggestion is to also unplug all drives that are not relevant to the OS when installing.

Comment: well I tried to do this with grub,but it seems I mistakenly wiped out the win10 boot records completely, now the grub shows my win7 along side ubuntu but not win10!

Comment: If you can still see the second partition you made for Win 10 boot from disc, and install Win 10, then it's just a matter of selecting boot OS once all 3 are installed. Make sure not to format the Linux partition or you'll have to do it all  again.